# building a jar with sources and javadoc

Tags: java, maven, jar, compilation, javadoc

I am trying to build a jar that include all the dependencies source and javadoc (*.java files), of my project and all the sub projects.
I am using maven assembly to do it, so far I manged to include only the dependencies.
This is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1-no-dep</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How can I force the plugin to include all the source and javadoc files into the output jar?

Comment: If you like to have all sources of the dependencies you need to define them as dependencies with the supplemental classifier `sources` to get them otherwise you won't get the sources packages. Furthermore in a jar-with-dependencies it does not make sense to package also the sources. Better would be to make a separate zip file which contains the sources.

Comment: Yes I know this will work but in this case I need to define in my pom all the dependency of my subproject and the subsub project and on... I was looking for more elegant way to do it

Answer (score 1):

This will produce a source.jar

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>BundleSources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create the [sources jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

and this one the [javadoc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <configuration>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: this is not working. I want the jar to include javadoc and sources of all the projects dependence.(not only of my code)